# Provide list of answers as targets when converting answer to comment

Tags: feature-request

(moderator stuff)

Currently "convert to comment" dialog on answer takes ID/URL and defaults to original question. However converting to comment on one of answers is much more common in practice (visitor dropping in to ask about answer) and it's pain to copy link (or look at ID) in advance. Doesn't seem like much but when you do these by dozens...

Please improve the dialog to offer original question and answers as targets to choose for converted comment.

Comment: Agreed. I usually hover over the link to the Answer I'm moving the comment to so I can see the ID ... but it's slow and annoying to have to go through that step.